# How to control snooze button for Alarm Class in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, alarm

I used the following code to `private static void CreateAlarm(double time)
        {

```
        var alarm = new Alarm("MyAlarm")

        {

            Content = "You have a meeting with your team now.",

            Sound = new Uri("/Sounds/preview.mp3", UriKind.Relative),

            BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time)


        };



        ScheduledActionService.Add(alarm);



    }`
```

to create an alarm clock for Windows Phone 7.As Alarm starts ,it gives "snooze" and "dismiss" option.When I click the snooze button,it takes me to my first page but I want to set snooze for 9min always.Someone told me that we cannot control snooze button but I think its very simple and there would be someway to do it.

Comment: you mean that when you click the snooze button your application should programmatically set the snooze time to 9 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this. However, in Mango (WP7.5) the snooze is already 9 minutes.